# How to get property and object bound to a WPF control

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, property-binding

I would like to resolve the object instance and the property a control is bound to consistently regardless of how the binding is defined.

I have done the following:

```
BindingExpression bindingExpression = 
baseEdit.GetBindingExpression(BaseEdit.EditValueProperty);

if (bindingExpression == null) continue;

Binding binding = bindingExpression.ParentBinding;

string propertyName = binding.Path.Path;
```

The above works in most scenarios but there are times where it does not give me what I want - and I understand why it doesn't but I cannot find a way to find what I want.

For example the following breaks what I have as it returns `DataContext.CurrentMileage` which is not what I want.  I want only `CurrentMileage`.

```xml
{Binding DataContext.CurrentMileage, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type view:ViewBase}}}
```

Comment: Note that the binding is to the `CurrentMilage` property of whatever object is in the `DataContext` of the `ViewBase` ancestor object. Hence you can't omit the `DataContext` from the property path. Having `CurrentMilage` only would mean that the binding goes to `CurrentMilage` of the `ViewBase` object directly, which is something different.

Comment: The DataContext is a ViewModel which contains the CurrentMileage.  CurrentMileage is not on the ViewBase.

Comment: I want to omit the DataContext from the path for my own purposes.  Not from the binding.... just to my propertyName variable.

Comment: You mean you simply want `binding.Path.Path.Split('.').Last()`, or do you also need to get what is in the `DataContext` part of the property path?

Comment: I need to get to the DataContext part also, as that would define whether I need the last split or may be the preceding one two.  For example, ViewModel is DataContext and binding is DataContext.Vehicle.Mileage.  The object it is bound to is ViewModel and the path I want is Vehicle.Mileage.

Comment: what you do when someone create such an binding: <TextBox DataContext="{Binding DataContext,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type view:ViewBase}}}" Text="{Binding Vehicle.Mileage}"/> or <TextBox DataContext="{Binding DataContext.Vehicle,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type view:ViewBase}}}" Text="{Binding Mileage}"/>